# MySQL - Sum of one column in one table with other column in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I Have two tables

Table1 is

```
    idno         marks
     1             12
     1             13
     1             22 
     2             32 
     2             35
     2             11  and so on
```

Table2 is

```
    idno          marks
     1              16
     1              22 
     1              21 
     2              35 
     2              16
     2              22   and so on
```

I am providing a form for user to enter the idno and submit

If user enters "1" in form and submit then the output should be

```
        Total Marks
            106
```

i.e the sum of all marks of Idno 1 in Table1 + sum of all marks of Idno 1 in table2

(12+13+22)+(16+22+21) = 106

and i am using the following code

```
<form id="form" action="sum.php" method="post">
<td><p align="center"> IDNO : <input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10"></p></td>
<input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result"
</form>

<?PHP
$user_name = "admin";
$password = "123456";
$database = "demo";
$server = "localhost";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$add = "SELECT htno, SUM(tech) 
FROM(SELECT htno, SUM(tm) AS tech FROM jbit WHERE htno='$id'
UNION ALL  
SELECT htno, SUM(tm1) AS tech  FROM hmm WHERE htno='$id') AS tech4 "; 
$result3 = mysql_query($add);
echo "
<center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center>
<tr>
<TH scope='col'>Total Marks</TH>
</tr><center>";
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>" . $row1['tech4']. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($db_handle);
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

but output is blank

please help me out

Comment: try `SUM(tm) AS tech1`, `SUM(tm1) AS tech2`, then `sum(tech1+tech2)`

Comment: echo mysql_error() after mysql_query ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing **GROUP by htno** in both parts of the union after WHERE clauses. Or you may consider removing *htno* field from SELECT clauses of the union.

```
 select sum(sm) from
   (select Sum(marks) sm from sums1 where idno=1
   union
   select Sum(marks) sm from sums2 where idno=1 ) ss
```

Tested this on mysql and it works

Comment: after adding, output is blank no change frnd @Ertunc

Comment: Did you check the source of the page in web browser? You can add die; in php to crash the app at specified point. Maybe your script is broken and not outputting any result.

Comment: no i have other queries in that page which are executing perfectly, only this query is not showing any output

Comment: @Aryan Did you revise your query as below                                   select sum(sm) from 
   (select Sum(marks) sm from sums1 where idno=1 
   union 
   select Sum(marks) sm from sums2 where idno=1 ) ss

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE htno='$id) AS tech4 "; 
               ^----here is the problem  should be htno='$id'
```

Comment: Question edited friend - could u please tell me the solution @NullPointer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(tech) AS tech4 FROM (
(SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM jbit WHERE htno='$id')
UNION ALL
(SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM hmm WHERE htno='$id')
) t1
```